# custom google maps titles

Tags: google-maps

i am trying to create tiles/Layers like this demo website.

http://www.clflightplanner.de/demos/dterra/

but I am new to this googlemaps. Are these tiles or layers?

Any book suggestion or tutorial link to kick off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are polygons drawn by `google.maps.Polygon` which is passed an array of latitude and longitude coordinates

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html

Comment: how do you know they use `google.maps.Polygon`? Their javascript is pretty cryptic, I cannot find even the `google.maps.Map` in their code!!! How can it even work?